# Classic ASP returns only single record from recordset on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, recordset

I have a been moved to a Windows 2008 Server where I need to host classic ASP functionality to a Oracle Database. I have configured the server to run classic ASP and have only found one issue where, when I execute a database request, only a single record is returned rather than the 999 ones available in the database. A run of the actual SQL command in SQLPlus show all records, so not sure what is going on:

```
selectScName = "select item from my_schema.col1"

Set dbObjT = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbObjT.open =  "MY-DB-CONNECTION"
Set RSdbTest = dbObjT.Execute(selectScName)

Do while not RSdbTest.EOF
         Response.Write(RSdbTest("col1") & "<br>")
      RSdbTest.MoveNext
     loop
RSdbTest.Close
Set RSdbTest = nothing
dbObjT.Close
Set dbObjT = nothing
```

Comment: Your ASP code looks fine.  I've no experience with Oracle myself, but I believe that you need to use an explicit cursor for multiple record queries, here's a link - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch06_03.htm

Comment: And here's the link I was really looking for http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255043

Comment: Just as a suggestion, before you start reading, can you just make sure the records set is at the start (I think the code is RsdbTest.MoveFirst())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think used .MaxReords=1 statement before this code. check it